# How to pass a param list of PropertyExpression

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, params-keyword

I have a generic repository in which I'm trying to include a function that accepts a variable list of child tables to eagerly load. The function looks thus:

```
    public IQueryable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeEntities)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = this._dbSet.Where(e => !e.Deleted).Where(predicate);
        foreach (var entity in includeEntities)
        {
            query.Include(entity);
        }
        return query;
    }
```

It works but I'm concerned about the `object` reference.

Using the function thus:

```
var foundEntities = Repository.Entities.FindBy(i => i.Id == targetId, i => i.Orders, i => i.Invoices);
```

The params passed in the `includeEntites` array are of type `System.Linq.Expressions.PropertyExpression` which is unfortunately an internal class so I can't make the function signature:

```
public IQueryable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<T, System.Linq.Expressions.PropertyExpression>>[] includeEntities)
```

as I'd like. Any thoughts?

Comment: Instead of `PropertyExpression`, could you use `MemberExpression`?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the lambda expressions of a type `PropertyExpression` don't always resolve to a `MemberExpression`.